# How to get the newest image (named highest number) from a server to show on a website?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

A partner is uploading some images to a server that is accessible by URL without login. The newest image gets the highest number in the end of the name. There's a bunch of different digits in the start of the name so I need to target the 4th last digits of the name and display that image. Would be nice to automate this once a day so I don't have to do this every day for 2 years.

What I have figured out is that this should be done with PHP? (Maybe javascript can do this?). I have looked up a bunch of different things but it's overwhelmingly much for me to figure out how to put something togheter without knowing much of basic PHP and JS, although I'm diving into javascript at the moment and PHP is highly interesting.

This is for a wordpress website and I only do CSS and basic HTML normally but I have experience with C++. I have used Fotorama.io and linked images manually from the server by URL. There's also some thumbnail images below with Fotorama. Would be really nice to get the previous images there but most importantly is the main picture that shows big.

Edit: Sorry for not being specific enough. The files were on a different server. I asked to get the files on the same server as the website and they now get loaded in to its own folder. When I go to the folder-URL then all the images are listed.

The files are imported with the name of "image19-09-17_10-59-55-57_00923.jpg" as the 923rd picture in the folder.

Comment: Do you have access to the image server's filesystem at all? Or do you just have access through web server / public URL?

Comment: Is your partner uploading the images on your server or another server? Please edit your question and add a detailed explanation about the setup, or we won't have a clue how to solve your issue. Currently, the question is too unspecific and broad.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I updated my question. Let me know if I need to be more specific and I will look into it. Am trying.

Comment: @KoalaYeung I had access through FTP login and I looked into it and found out that the password would be visible trough the solution I found so the images are now uploaded to the same webserver in own folder.

Comment: OK, so you question has nothing to do with *FTP*, now, right? You want to scan a *local* (relatively to your webserver/PHP script) folder, correct?

Comment: I think you may simply GET the HTML of the directory listing page, parse all the links and find the URL with the highest number in the image file name, right?

Comment: @KoalaYeung First, it's quite a bad practice to have a directory listing page generation enabled. So I hope OP does not have it. And even if it was enabled, it's such an overkill to do it this way, when you are finding a *local* file.

Comment: Is it possible to have a script written and run on the image upload server that returns the latest image file URL? That seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: @KoalaYeung Yes, the problem, I think, is that the file names I get these images in are very long and also have some random numbers in them, also some wierd time format in the name but the end of the name is the number of the last image + 1. So I think that's the value I need to go after. Upload (not upload, the images are already uploaded, but display) the image from another folder with the highest number in the end of the name. You think javascript is the best solution?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I agree, directory listing is not optimal and I usually turn that off in the htaccess file.

Comment: It shouldn't be more complicated than just iterate through the files in that folder and check the part of the filename you need to check. We can probably help with that if you show us some example filenames and which part you want to sort them on.

Comment: yes @MagnusEriksson, "image19-09-17_10-44-55-57_01922.jpg", meaning this is the image number 1922. The server is filling up space with a lot of images so I need to sort that out later too.

Comment: I believe the middle number might be the clock time and not random.

Comment: So you want to extract the part `00923` from each file name and pick the file with the highest number? (*"4th last digits of the name"* is not clear to me)

Comment: Or use date/time format if that's the easiest solution? Could you help/point me in the right direction maybe? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: By "date/time format", do you mean this part? `19-09-17_10-59-55-57`? Do all the files have the same name format (including the fixed `image` prefix)? I.e. `imageYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS-MM_NNNNN.jpg`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @MartinPrikryl. They have the same format as you write.

Answer (score 0):

Your files have a file name format that basically puts the latest file the last in lexicographical order.

So just call [`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and pick the last file returned.

```
$files = glob("/path/*");
$latest = array_pop($files);
```